# API REST, when GET limit collides semantics

Tags: rest, api, http

When building an API REST, querying data should be done with a GET request. It's textbook. But GET is limited to low thousands characters range whereas POST does not bear such limitation (usually few MB).

So how do you cope with requests above the GET limit (think you have an API and you send an array of zipcodes, to get in return an array of names)?

In this particuliar case, I use POST since the array is above GET limits. It works but some people would think it's shameful.
So I wonder what's the rule to deal with such problem.
Requesting n times an unique zipcode is not an option for obvious performance reasons.

Comment: Are there patterns to the zip code? Could you perhaps use a range? e.g. `code=AB-XY`? Then general consensus for scenarios like that is to just use POST (despite the fact it goes against the grain).

Comment: No, assume zip codes are random (that was just an exemple, could be securities such as equity ISIN, etc...).

Comment: in that case I can't see anyway you can reduce the size of the URLs other than batching the requests but that's just messy. I'd go with POST, sometimes you have to sacrifice practicality over best practise.

Answer (score 0):

REST is just a generalization of the Web we are so used everyday. You can basically apply the same techniques in a REST environment that you apply to the Web. I.e. if there are a pletora of options available or free-text input that easily can exceed 2k characters you either can use POST to perform the invocation and send the data through the payload or redesign your approach. The former approch lacks support of valueable properties like `safe` and `idempotent` and may also avoid caching at all.

An other approch would be to model the choices a client can send as own resource. This allows certain configurations to be "named" and reused and being invoked with a simple GET request. In HTML a client could request all available configurations and select one that fits its need or ask the server for a form-page to input the choices and send them via POST to the server. This configuration will later on appear in future client requests for available configurations.

The actual structure of the URI pointing to that particular resource is usually not of importance to the client as a meaningful (link-relation) name should be used in order to determine which URI to invoke. Such resources can easily be invoked via `GET` which automatically provide the above mentioned properties. The critical part here is to find a naming-scheme that makes sense to clients so a client understands what this URI is actually good for.

Also the translation of the form to a REST architecture might not be the most trivial thing to do. In HTML the spec already includes semantics for forms and choices as well as for links. You could either reuse that particular feature or come up with your own media-type, i.e. `application/vnd.form-hal+json` that might be an extension of HAL-JSON, which already defines the structure of links. This media-type in particular tells the recipient of such a payload that data received in such a representation is intended for being presented in forms or represents form-data and therefore may contain user-input to show or store.

A client not finding any of the current query configurations fitting might therefore ask the server on how to create a new configuration. The server will inform the client with a payload of an above mentioned representation which if understood by the client will lead the client to either show the data in a meaningful way to its user or even allows the client to take that representation and fill in the required information on its own and send it via POST back to the server in order to create a new query configuration. A further request of available configurations should then also list the new one.

As you hopefully can see, the same technique that is used in the Web can be applied to REST as well. Such an approch scales rather well and is in additon to that quite robust in practice as the server teaches the client on how to send requests and the client does not need any a-priori information about the service. This technique also explains what Fielding asked for in one of his [blog posts](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven):

> A REST API **should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types.** Any effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules for a media type (and, in most cases, already defined by existing media types). [*Failure here implies that out-of-band information is driving interaction instead of hypertext.*]